# How to access the powershell v2 ctp3 assembies from c#

Tags: c#, powershell-2.0

I know the System.Management.Automation.dll assembly is put in the GAC, version 6.1.6949.0, 
which I know is the ctp3 assembly. When I browse for it, in c# to add it as a reference from within VS 2008TS, it doesn't show up. Anybody know how I can add it.

regards
scope_creep

Answer (score 1):

From a Visual Studio console application, I right-clicked on References, selected Add Reference from the popup menu, clicked the Browse tab in the Add Reference dialog, and navigated to

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

I then clicked on System.Management.Automation.dll, clicked the OK button, and it added the reference to my project.

Granted, this is probably not the CTP3 DLL, but you get the idea.  Make sure you have a reference copy of the desired DLL somewhere other than the GAC for adding the reference.

Comment: Hey Robert, 
It was straight forward with the v1 reference assemblies stored in program files, but for some reason it will not browse to the v2ctp3 assemblies in the GAC. Why does ot now browse, when I know that version ins in their.,

Comment: Can you browse it in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

Well you learn something new every day. Apparently the GAC is a runtime store, and should be used as such. Any dll signed and put in their is not available for browsing for add reference in VS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024739/how-to-reference-a-self-made-assembly-that-is-installed-in-the-gac-in-visual-stud

Answer (score 0):

For my case i found the updates after installing the ctp in the below path. hope it helps.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Management.Automation\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35