# How can I configure my Setup Project to add an assembly to the GAC during the installation process?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, assemblies, gac, setup-project

First of all, I'm aware of ***[why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113186/why-is-my-assembly-not-visible-in-add-reference-net-when-installed-to-the-ga)*** it doesn't appear in the "Add References" dialog. I also know how I can [manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024739/how-to-reference-a-self-made-assembly-that-is-installed-in-the-gac-in-visual-stud) add it.

What I want to know is how I should change my **Setup Project** (in Visual Studio) so that the assembly appear in "Add reference" dialog. Should I add a new target location or a custom action or something else?

I currently just put the "Primary Output" in the "Global Assembly Cache Folder"

Comment: Sorry, but if u know the answer .. then what is the question ? Make us more clear with some example.

Comment: The question is how I do it in practice in visual studio setup projects. Is it "Add Custom Action", a new target location or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You modify the setup project to create the necessary registry keys on installation and remove them on uninstallation.

Note that you ideally need to be deploying the assemblies to a 'proper' installation folder as well, and then use that deployment folder as the target folder for the AssemblyReferences key - in the same way that Microsoft deploys the Reference Assemblies folders for its components.

### Update

Here's a link to a demonstration VS2010 solution I have prepared for you: https://docs.google.com/leaf?id=0Bw_NnV9fhgmgNGE0N2JjYWYtNmVlNC00YjZhLWJlMGMtMDAyMTllYzU4Y2Fi&hl=en&authkey=CPTv8bUI which will do exactly what you want.

After building and running the installation project the 'AddReferenceDemo' assembly will appear in the 'Assemblies\Extensions' tab of the Add Reference Dialog.

Here's how I built it:

- Add primary output to 'Application Folder' in File System view.
- Add primary output to 'Global Assembly Cache Folder' special folder ***(optional - only if you want the file in the GAC as well)***
- In the Registry viewer add the keys `Software\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319\AssemblyFoldersEx\[ProductName]` using the UI (you have to create each one).  The `[ProductName]` here should be used **verbatim** as it's a shortcut for whatever the product name is set in setup project's properties.
- Add a default string value under that (i.e. no name) with the value `[TARGETDIR]` - again copied verbatim.  Note that this will ultimately be set to whichever installation folder the user chooses when they run your installer.

Build and run the installer.

Also it doesn't appear the the new registry entry is *ever* deleted on uninstall, even if you mark it as such.  Possibly the value needs to be marked for deletion as well.

Note that the installer should be marked as 'x86' target platform so that the correct Registry node (Software or Software\Wow6432Node) is used depending on the bitness of the target platform.  It doesn't matter if you're deploying x64 assemblies - it's bitness of the installer that you're setting here and it affects the view of the registry etc.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, yes. I know. But I suck at visual studios setup projects. I want to know how I do it in the project, not in theory.

Comment: @jgauffin - I have a solution, walkthrough and demo for you for VS2010.  See updated answer

Answer (score 0):

The add references dialog (whether the original one or the enhanced one from Productivity Power Tools) does not search the GAC for assemblies.

Rather it searches the folders specified in one of several places in the registry (depending on .NET framework version and profile).

Eg. `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0\AssemblyFoldersEx`

However I don't think the rules about what folders are searched are clearly defined, so some trial and error may be needed.

Comment: I updated the question and tried to make it more clear what I want.